# Get string between 2 other strings - Python 2.7.8

Tags: python, string

So I have a huge string, where some strings occur a lot. I need the text in between.

```
"I don't need this""This is what I need""I also don't need this."
```

This happens many times, and I'd like all the strings I need in a list.

There's also a lot of special characters, but no ' so I can use them for strings.

I have tried with the re library, but I can't get it to work.

I tried splitting too

```
listy = hugestring.split('delim1')
for element in listy:
    element = element.split('delim2')
```

But the second splitting doesn't work.

Comment: So whats problem now ? and what you try by yourself ?

Comment: I have tried splitting the string into a list for the first repeating section, and then splitting every element in the list for the second repeating section. It didn't split the second time though, so I just got a huge list where each element starts with the string I need.

Comment: whats desire string that you want ? and what parts of the string is that you dont want ?

Comment: I have edited the main text.

Comment: how you know second for doesn't work ? whats `delim1` ? if its not in string the result would be empty !!!

Comment: delim1 is the "I don't need this" part, and delim2 is the "I also don't need this."
I tried print listy[1] but it only has one element, though it should have two!

Comment: i add an answer help me for got an answer together !

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex like this

```
>>> import re
>>> your_str = "foo This is what I need bar foo This is what I need too bar"
>>> left_delim = "foo "
>>> right_delim = " bar"
>>> pattern  = "(?<={})[ \w]*?(?={})".format(left_delim,right_delim)
>>> re.findall(pattern,your_str)
['This is what I need', 'This is what I need too']
```

Comment: This only finds one string, I need a lot of strings.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a list of all strings within quotes contained in a string:

```
import re
in_str = "I don't need this\"This is what I need\"I also don't need this."
out_str = re.findall(r'\"(.+?)\"', in_str)
print out_str
```

So in the above example, `print out_str[0]` will give you what you need as there's only the one quote in there.

Comment: I don't get how this works. Where do I input my string? Does it output it as a list?

Comment: What don't you get about this? Your string is in the in_str variable which then gets parsed through the reg ex into out_str (the output variable).

If your string is a user input, just make the user input map into in_str (or whatever variable the re.findall() function calls!)

Answer (score 0):

this is the result of what you say in comment , so whats problem now ?:

```
>>> n= s.split("I don't need this")
['', "This is what I needI also don't need this."]
>>> [i.split("I also don't need this") for i in n]
[[''], ['This is what I need', '.']]
```